# Universal function to get the value from a entry, combobox, text

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

Is it possible to make a working universal function to get a value from e.g an entry?

Something like this:

```
def returnInput(obj):
    _x = StringVar()
    obj.configure(textvariable=_x)
    return str(_x.get())
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: you code make no sense - it gets data from `StringVar` before someone put anything in object. You have to assign `StringVar` to `Entry` at start, but you get value from `StringVar` in different moments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not like that. You can however define a function like the following:

```
def uni_get(widget):

    wgt_typ = type(widget).__name__
    if wgt_typ == 'Label' or wgt_typ == 'Button':
        disp_str = widget['text']

    elif wgt_typ == 'Text':
        disp_str = widget.get('1.0', 'end-1c')

    elif wgt_typ == 'Combobox' or wgt_typ == 'Entry':
        disp_str = widget.get()

    return disp_str
```

---

Demo Example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def uni_get():
    #to dynamically update the selected widget passed to uni_get
    global cbb
    widget = root.winfo_children()[cbb.current()]

    wgt_typ = type(widget).__name__
    if wgt_typ == 'Label' or wgt_typ == 'Button':
        disp_str = widget['text']

    elif wgt_typ == 'Text':
        disp_str = widget.get('1.0', 'end-1c')

    elif wgt_typ == 'Combobox' or wgt_typ == 'Entry':
        disp_str = widget.get()

    print(disp_str)

root = tk.Tk()

cbb = ttk.Combobox(root)
ent = tk.Entry(root)
txt = tk.Text(root)
lbl = tk.Label(root)
btn = tk.Button(root, command=uni_get)

###     default widget configs      ###
cbb['values'] = ["Combobox", "Entry", "Text", "Label", "Button"]
cbb.current(0)
ent.insert('0', "Entry")
txt.insert('1.0', "Text")
lbl['text'] = "Label"
btn['text'] = "Button"

###     layout      ###
cbb.pack()
ent.pack()
txt.pack()
lbl.pack()
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I get this error: `Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\PyEngine\gui.py", line 75, in save
    x1 = uni_get(X)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\PyEngine\gui.py", line 70, in uni_get
    print(disp_str)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'disp_str' referenced before assignment`

Comment: You must be making a mistake when modifying the function. Try adding `global disp_str` in your function as the first line.

Comment: Found the error, it was in another Function. Now it works thank you very much!

Comment: @D.W No problem.

Answer (score 1):

For most tkinter text functions, var = obj.get() works most often, with a few exceptions.

For example:

```
entry.get()
listbox.get(listbox.curselection())
```

or exportselection for a combobox.

It would be seriously easier to use these methods than to create a function.

Comment: Your first statement is false. `obj.get()` will only work with the Entry widget (and the `*Var` classes). The other widgets that use `get()` need one or more arguments.

Comment: That just proves my point about using a function when using variable assignment could be easier.